# It appears I have a memory leak in the process unknown -1

Tags: memory-leaks

Paged table keeps getting larger and larger the longer I leave my computer on, it appears it's from an unknown process, what can I do to find out what it is?

[image: alt]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I began uninstalling/re-installing everything i have installed in the past week a few at a time in hopes of it being one of those, the last two things I have uninstalled were Razer Surround Sound and Intel 3.0  Drivers, one of these two was causing the leak as the leak has now stopped.

I'm leaning towards Razer Surround as I just googled it and other people are having the same issue.

Comment: I had the same problem, my `"Unknown (-1)"` took 12GB after 8 days without reboot. I uninstalled several programs and the problem is gone now. However hard to say which one was responsible: ___Razer Synapse, Paragon Hard Disk Manager, Qualcomm Atheros Client, UNi Xonar Drivers, PC Connectivity Solution, Nokia Driver, WinPcap, Nvidia PhysX, Logitech Webcam___

Answer (score 0):

I dont think its an memory leak, seems your system got infected by a virus which is creating dump pages . And also it is from an unknown process which implicitly notifying that it might be a virus. Download and install antivirus and malware detector tool and scan it once.

Comment: I've already done so, nothing comes up.

Comment: Can you post the source location of processes.

Comment: All it gives me is that it is in the page table.

Comment: Well viruses these days has better things to do than filling your memory with dump pages :). They want to stay hidden. Also they are often made by very skilled programmers that know how to avoid memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should read this:

Identify the processes with the largest usage. You might see N/A and “Unknown (-1)” as process names.
N/A contains pages not associated to any processes such as driver pool memory.
“Unknown (-1)” contains shareable pages.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/test/wpt/memory-footprint-optimization-exercise-1

Answer (score 0):

I know this is super old but I'll post what was causing my issue in case it benefits someone else.

In my case, the memory "leak" was caused by a program "synTPenh.exe" (Synaptics driver) because I added it to run at startup using the Task Scheduler, but it caused it to start twice since I didn't remove the default startup entry of the Synaptics service... Long story short, their service will keep starting and stopping "synTPenh.exe" every second and apparently that's why after a few hours of using my laptop, the "Page Table" and "Paged Pool" in RAMMap increases from around 300MB each to above 1GB or so.

The way I noticed the issue (since "unknown (-1)" is not helpful) is that in RAMMap's second tab "process" or what not, I found thousands of entries all named "SynTPenh.exe". And I detected the issue of the program continuously restarting with the help of "Process Explorer" since it colors in red whatever process has just stopped.

To summarize: check if any program/driver is starting thousands of instances of itself.
I hope this helps!